# What is meant by local repository and remote repository in Maven?

Tags: maven, terminology

I am reading up [Maven - The complete reference](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-relationships.html) and came across this

> Maven assumes that the parent POM is available from the local repository, or available in the parent directory (`../pom.xml`) of the current project. If neither location is valid this default behavior may be overridden via the relativePath element.

What exactly is meant by local and remote repository for a Maven installation and a project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A local repository is a local directory structure that caches artifacts downloaded from remote repositories, or those that are manually installed (eg from the command line option).

A remote repository is a web service (defined by a URL) that contains versioned artifacts. This might be as simple as an Apache server, or a full-blown Maven repository, such as [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview), that allows uploading, permissions based on a user directory, etc.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html

Answer (score 3):

By default, Maven will source dependencies from, and install dependencies to, your local `.m2` repository. This is a precedence rule, and your `.m2` acts like a cache where Maven can source dependencies before downloading them remotely. You can bypass this behaviour like so: `mvn -U ...` (see `mvn --help`).

Your local `.m2` can be found under `C:\Users\{user}\.m2` on Windows, or `/home/{user}/.m2` on Linux. If you do a `mvn install`, your project will be locally installed under the said `.m2` repository.

A remote repository is a Maven repository, just like your local `.m2` repository, hosted for you to source dependencies from, e.g. [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Local repository is a repo. Into your local system, when you compile or install project all required dependencies downloaded into your local repo.
When you're working with your project, then Maven first tries to get dependencies from local. If it's not available, then Maven will try to download the dependency from a central repository.

central repo. is a online repo, which is provided by maven itself.

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.